# What's a word for a person who deals or takes care of other people's problems?

Tags: single-word-requests, titles

I need a precise word or title that describes a person who takes care of other people's problems.A person who covers up someone's tracks or cleans up someone's mess.

Imagine, a person who has too many connections, has an authority and everybody respects him, but always stays in the shadows and only reveals himself when someone asks him to do their dirty work.

Comment: We need more context? What kind of problems? Examples?

Comment: Can you provide some context to the question? Are you asking about a person who is helpful, or someone who solves problems someone cannot do for themselves, or some other use?

Comment: Also...it is someone who helps another by request or who just kind of sticks their nose into someone else's business?

Comment: Concierge maybe?

Comment: I've added a few things. Hope it will help.

Comment: secretary, not just the office type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fixer** comes to mind

> A person who makes arrangements for other people, especially of an
>   illicit or devious kind. 
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fixer)

Consider the Showtime series *Ray Donovan*.  See the [Premise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Donovan).

Comment: Sometimes also called a "cleaner".